# How do companies listed in the US stock exchages choose when they report their earnings

Tags: united-states, stocks, corporate-earnings

Do they just pick a date?  Or are there some archaic rules governing earning report dates..

Updated from link provided by  Bob Baerker.

The essential SEC requirements are that each public company file quarterly earnings reports on Form 10-Q or 10-QSB and yearly earnings reports on Form 10-K or 10-KSB.

A company can announce earnings publicly whenever it chooses, provided it follows the timing guidelines set by the SEC.

---

So they can pick whichever day they want within an SEC prescribed window...

Comment: For the US: https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/04/050604.asp

Comment: Don't worry.  Someone will probably come along and tell me that my comment is an answer and that I had better convert it or else.  Just go with the flow.  Swimming upstream is tiresome :->)

Comment: ? First, I am not the DV. The question, in my opinion, is relevant. But the answer, from Bob's link has been added to question, as an edit. Which is just strange. Again, in my opinion.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer  Bob chose to answer in a comment.  So for the sake of any future reader wanting to ask the same question, i pulled the key paragraphs out of his link.

Comment: Well, he better convert it, or else. (I am joking. I did not wish to disappoint him.) The question has made it to the review queue, and I am not voting on it. A mod vote is a hard close. I will leave it to members. (And if I clean up comments, I'll leave his link, if he doesn't convert)